# Error message installing npm

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, installation, root, npm-install

I get the following message when I type npm install from the root directory

> $ npm install
>   npm ERR! install Couldn't read dependencies
>   npm ERR! Darwin 15.3.0
>   npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install"
>   npm ERR! node v4.4.0
>   npm ERR! npm  v2.14.20
>   npm ERR! path /package.json
>   npm ERR! code ENOPACKAGEJSON
>   npm ERR! errno -2
>   npm ERR! syscall open
>
> npm ERR! package.json ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/package.json'
>   npm ERR! package.json This is most likely not a problem with npm itself.
>   npm ERR! package.json npm can't find a package.json file in your current directory.
>   npm ERR! Darwin 15.3.0
>   npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install"
>   npm ERR! node v4.4.0
>   npm ERR! npm  v2.14.20
>   npm ERR! path npm-debug.log.3965331654
>   npm ERR! code EACCES
>   npm ERR! errno -13
>   npm ERR! syscall open
>
> npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, open 'npm-debug.log.3965331654'
>   npm ERR!     at Error (native)
>   npm ERR!  { [Error: EACCES: permission denied, open 'npm-debug.log.3965331654']
>   npm ERR!   errno: -13,
>   npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
>   npm ERR!   syscall: 'open',
>   npm ERR!   path: 'npm-debug.log.3965331654' }
>   npm ERR! 
>   npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.
>
> npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
>   npm ERR!     /npm-debug.

Comment: are you trying to install / update npm?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably you are trying to run this code in empty directory. This is not right. `npm install` command installs all packages and dependencies which are listed in package.json file.

If you want to start npm project and make `npm install` run successfully, first run `npm init` command. This will create you package.json and there you will be able to enter all the packages and deps. Then you will be able to run `npm install`

Here is a [tutorial](https://egghead.io/lessons/javascript-how-to-write-a-javascript-library-configuring-npm-and-creating-a-package-json)
And [one](http://www.sitepoint.com/beginners-guide-node-package-manager/) more